# Another trigonometric equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Show that :
$$31+8\sqrt{15}=16(1+\cos 6^{\circ})(1+\cos 42^{\circ})(1+\cos 66^{\circ})(1-\cos 78^{\circ})$$

Comment: What have you tried? Did your lecturer not do an example of these? Do you know complex numbers and/or algebraic numbers?

Comment: Where are you getting these? Why are they of interest to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is how the problem came into being. But, I think this to be a legitimate way.

$$(1+\cos 6^{\circ})(1+\cos 42^{\circ})(1+\cos 66^{\circ})(1-\cos 78^{\circ})$$

$$=(1+\cos 6^{\circ})(1+\cos 66^{\circ})(1-\cos 78^{\circ})(1+\cos 42^{\circ})$$

$$=(1+\cos 6^{\circ}+\cos 66^{\circ}+\cos 6^{\circ}\cos 66^{\circ})(1+\cos 42^{\circ}-\cos 78^{\circ}-\cos 42^{\circ}\cos 78^{\circ})$$

$$=\{1+2\cos 30^{\circ}\cos 36^{\circ}+\frac12(\cos60^\circ+\cos72^\circ)\}
\{1+2\sin 18^{\circ}\sin60^{\circ}-\frac12(\cos36^\circ+\cos120^\circ)\}$$

(Applying

$2\cos A\cos B=\cos(A-B)+\cos(A+B),$

$ \cos2C+\cos2D=2\cos(C-D)\cos(C+D)$ and $\cos2C-\cos2D=-2\sin(C-D)\sin(C+D)$ )

Now, $\sin60^{\circ}=\cos 30^{\circ}=\frac{\sqrt3}2,\cos120^\circ=\cos(180-60)^\circ=-\cos60^\circ=-\frac12$

From [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/cos36.shtml), or [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090405224513AAwtYD9) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300081/how-to-find-the-exact-value-of-cos36-circ)  $\cos72^\circ=\sin 18^\circ=\frac{\sqrt5-1}4$ and $\cos36^\circ=\frac{\sqrt5+1}4$