# Why is $\cos(36°) = \frac{\phi}{2}$ where $\phi$ is the golden ratio?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, golden-ratio

A recent question had a comment which intrigued me, so I went to Wolfram Alpha and put in $\cos(36°)$ and it was half the golden ratio?  Why is $\cos(36^\circ) = \frac{\phi}{2}$? Is there a nice geometric proof? I have never heard this before and it's quite fascinating.
Is it a coincidence?

Is there something special about the angle $\frac{\pi}{5}$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827540/proving-trigonometric-equation-cos36-circ-cos72-circ-1-2

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Alternative_forms : "These correspond to the fact that the length of the diagonal of a regular pentagon is φ times the length of its side"

Comment: Thank you! I figured it would have been asked numerous

Comment: So why didn't you just google it?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I don't think that the question you cite is a good duplicate target.  First off, it is itself marked as a duplicate of another question.  Second, while computing $\cos(36^\circ)$ is a step in the argument that $\cos(36^\circ) - \cos(72^\circ) = 1/2$, that is, I think, not quite what this question is asking about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exact value for $\cos 36°$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763128/exact-value-for-cos-36) (I think that this is a better dupe target.)

Comment: @Xander, I have not proposed it to be duplicate, it  just shows how to calculate $\cos36^\circ$

Answer (score 0):

Because it's $\frac{\sin 72^\circ}{2\sin 36^\circ}=\frac{\sin 108^\circ}{2\sin 36^\circ}$, which by the sine rule, applied to a side-side-diagonal isosceles triangle of a rectangular pentagon, is $\frac{\varphi}{2}$.